# New Ceylon-project has un-openable 'module.ceylon'

Tags: ceylon

Having just created a new Ceylon project ('POSTtoFile'), and within it a new ceylon module called 'server', I would like to open this file:

```
POSTtoFile / source / server / server / module.ceylon
```

in order to specify the dependencies of the `server` module.

However, when double clicking on `module.ceylon`in the left pane (`Ceylong Explorer`), nothing happens. No empty file is shown. As I previously opened `run.ceylon`, the content of `run.ceylon`is still what is shown shown:

[image]

This is what I would like to write in `module.ceylon`:

```
"PosttoFile can receive a http POST request and download
 the received content to a file. Then it will terminate."
native ("jvm")
module server "1.0.0" {
    import ceylon.http.server "1.3.3";
    import ceylon.json "1.3.3";
    import ceylon.io "1.3.3";
}

// ceylon.http.common, ceylon.http.client, ceylon.http.server, and ceylon.uri
```

Comment: Does Eclipse's error log show anything?

Comment: no it doesn't show anything